# Angular material layout issue in IE11 for smaller screen resolution

Tags: flexbox, angular-material

I'm working on angular material layout, it's working fine in all the browsers including IE11, but for smaller screen resolutions, I'm facing content overlapping issue.
Here's the code I've tried:

HTML:

```
<div layout="row" layout-sm="column" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap>
    <div class="innersection" flex="25" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100" layout="row">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting<br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
    <div class="innersection" flex="25" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100" layout="row">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
    <div class="innersection" flex="25" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100" layout="row">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting<br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
    <div class="innersection" flex="25" flex-sm="100" flex-xs="100" layout="row">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.innersection {
  background: #fff; padding:8px; border:1px solid;
}
```

Here's working fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjb0soLn/17/

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Add `flex: auto` to `.innersection`. http://jsfiddle.net/xjb0soLn/18/

Comment: Thanks. But is there any solution without adding CSS style, something like  adding flex="auto"?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Angular. Maybe somebody else can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjb0soLn/22/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div layout-gt-sm="row" layout-wrap>
    <div class="innersection" flex-gt-sm="25">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting<br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
    <div class="innersection" flex-gt-sm="25">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
    <div class="innersection" flex-gt-sm="25">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting<br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
<div class="innersection" flex-gt-sm="25">
        Title <br/><br/> Description:
        <br/> Manage your account, username and password setting
    </div>
</div>
```